# class_has for Moops

Tags: perl, moops

Is there something like [`MooseX::ClassAttribute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::ClassAttribute) for [Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops)?

Note, that I want static/class attributes using the `Moo` backend, as I do not want to bring in the `Moose` backend.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [MooX::ClassAttribute](http://p3rl.org/MooX::ClassAttribute), but there are often better ways to do things than class attributes.

If you want "ro"  class data, then consider `use constant` instead.

If you want "rw" data,  then consider an `our` variable, which has an advantage over class attributes: you can use the `local` keyword to dynamically scope changes. (And if you want type constraints, then [Type::Tie](http://p3rl.org/Type::Tie).)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is [`MooX::ClassAttribute`](https://metacpan.org/module/MooX::ClassAttribute)

*"declare class attributes Moose-style... but without Moose"*